# Jobs are not appearing as rich card under Google job search results page

Tags: google-search, google-rich-snippets

Jobs from my website are not appearing as rich card under Google jobs search results. Google structured data testing tool is not showing any error. Under webmaster tool rich card section, Google is showing that rich card found. When I search my jobs, it appears under Google search results but as normal search results not as a rich card.

**Here is a sample job URL:** https://www.caqh.org/about/careers/panth-lead-software-engineer

Can anyone please tell me what is the exact reason of not showing the jobs as rich card?

Comment: Unless you have an issue with your markup (in which case you have to include a minimal example in the question post), this question doesn’t seem to be on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

When I check your website schema using a "structured data testing tool" it shows the organization fields only. To be listed in Google job card results you should implement proper job card schema.
Here I implemented Google Job card schema for my blog [https://speedraftaar.com](https://speedraftaar.com/)

You can check schema of this page
https://speedraftaar.com/ongc-recruitment-2020-apply-for-72-associate-consultant-junior-consultant-posts

[image: Google Job card image]